# MySQL: Copy postid from one table to another in same database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a plugin first time :) this required own table and will use postid as a key. Now things are seems fine but only one issue is..

I want to copy `postid` from `posts` table to `postid` in `counter` table. How can I write query to copy only for one time. I have write function for new posts so it will add `postid` to `counter` table when new post created but for old.

I only know the basic simple query but this is complex for me need help. please

Comment: Make `counter.postid` unique and do `INSERT` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sql should do the trick provided counter is empty to start and you have defaults set for other fields in counter

```
insert into counter(postid) 
select postid 
from posts
```